# Using MySql in Google Sheets, I'd like to use a sheet range to limit my results

Tags: mysql, select, google-sheets

I'm creating a MySQL select statement query. I'd like to limit my results to those rows where a specific column matches one of several possible limiters in a static range on another sheet within the same workbook.

Basically, I want the select statement to be something like this:

```
var RANGE = ....'Data!A1:A20'
select * where customer = RANGE
```

I'm looking for the specific language to do this within Google Sheets.

Comment: I used this language to get the range: var ListID = sheet.getRange('E4:E50').getValues() 

That seemed to work. 

What I can't figure out is how to allow the multiple values obtained in that range to all serve as possible variables in the select statement.

Comment: Whenever you used getValues() the data is returned as a two dimensional array.  So in your case the array looks like this `[[E4],[E5],[E6],...]` so you have to loop through the array getting data like `ListID[0][0],ListID[1][0],ListID[2][0],...` Hope that helps.  I have a document and video about the problems I've had with these arrays [here](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/javascript-array-difficulties).